# call postback from ashx

Tags: asp.net

I have MyPage.aspx file and a button within. The button has server click event:

```
protected void Button_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ....
    ....
    ....
}
```

I have another file MyAshx.ashx file and I want to call the Button_OnClick function from it. Is there any to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but you can extract / refactor the method body into a method in another class that is accessible to both. Your method body doesn't use the object sender or EventArgs e arguments, does it?

Comment: The method needs MyPage initialize (all the page events up to the button event) in order to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to access protected method of a class to another class. It is better to write a public method in public class and call it via Button's click and ashx handler.

Comment: The method needs MyPage initialization - please see my comment to olivehour.